# Laravel 5 how to export PATH (homestead and installer)

Tags: laravel, path, homestead

I'm using zsh. Want to figure out, how to export Laravel installer and homestead PATH?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a `.zsh_profile` file in your home (`~/`) directory. In that file you have to add line `export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin` and restart your ZSH

So you will be able to access anything that you installed with:

`$ composer require-global`

Like, if you have `$ composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`, you will be able to access your laravel installer. Same goes for homestead.

If you want to do more with **.zsh_profile**, you can have a look here: https://github.com/slavingia/dotfiles/blob/master/.zsh_profile